# How to configure a non-regular display (1920x480 CET) for Pi3 and Pi4 running Raspbian buster?

Tags: pi-3b+, pi-4, raspbian-buster, raspberry-pi-os-buster

I have weird display of resolution 1920x480.

I have hardwares both raspberry Pi3 B+ and Pi4, both running raspbain buster latest stable release.

When connected to the display (both the Pi3 and Pi4), the display glows for a moment and doesn't show anything.

First I thought it might the screen it-self. So I connected the screen to an Intel NUC running Ubuntu 20.04. Since Ubuntu has a nice display manager, it could query the screen and got, from the first boot, the right configuration and was working like a charm.

But not on raspbian.

So after reading the raspberry pi [official documentation on video and HDMI](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md) setup I tried running the command:

```
/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -d edid.dat; /opt/vc/bin/edidparser edid.dat
```

It gave me the following dump:

```
Enabling fuzzy format match...
Parsing edid.dat...
HDMI:EDID version 1.3, 1 extensions, screen size 15x10 cm
HDMI:EDID features - videodef 0x80 !standby !suspend !active off; colour encoding:RGB444|YCbCr422; sRGB is not default colourspace; preferred format is native; does not support GTF
HDMI:EDID ignored unknown descriptor tag 0x0
HDMI:EDID found monitor range descriptor tag 0xfd
HDMI:EDID monitor range offsets: V min=0, V max=0, H min=0, H max=0
HDMI:EDID monitor range: vertical is 48-62 Hz, horizontal is 30-70 kHz, max pixel clock is 150 MHz
HDMI:EDID monitor range does not support GTF
HDMI:EDID found monitor name descriptor tag 0xfc
HDMI:EDID monitor name is 13728626231
HDMI:EDID failed to find a matching detail format for 480x1920p hfp:30 hs:30 hbp:30 vfp:6 vs:6 vbp:6 pixel clock:66 MHz
HDMI:EDID calculated refresh rate is 60 Hz
HDMI:EDID guessing the format to be 480x1920p @60 Hz
HDMI:EDID found unknown detail timing format: 480x1920p hfp:30 hs:30 hbp:30 vfp:6 vs:6 vbp:6 pixel clock:66 MHz
HDMI:EDID established timing I/II bytes are 00 00 00
HDMI:EDID standard timings block x 8: 0x01C1 0101 01C1 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 
HDMI:EDID unknown standard timing 256x144 @ 61 Hz aspect ratio (16:9)
HDMI:EDID unknown standard timing 256x144 @ 61 Hz aspect ratio (16:9)
HDMI:EDID parsing v3 CEA extension 0
HDMI:EDID monitor support - underscan IT formats:yes, basic audio:yes, yuv444:yes, yuv422:yes, #native DTD:1
HDMI:EDID found preferred CEA detail timing format: 1920x1080i @ 60 Hz (5)
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 4, 1280x720p @ 60Hz (native)
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 4, 1280x720p @ 60Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 4, 1280x720p @ 60Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 4, 1280x720p @ 60Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 19, 1280x720p @ 50Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 4, 1280x720p @ 60Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 4, 1280x720p @ 60Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 2, 720x480p @ 60Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 1, 640x480p @ 60Hz 
HDMI:EDID does not understand CEA format code 0
HDMI:EDID found audio format 2 channels PCM, sample rate: 32|44|48|88|96|176|192 kHz, sample size: 16|20|24 bits
HDMI:EDID found HDMI VSDB length 7
HDMI:EDID HDMI VSDB has physical address 0.0.0.0
HDMI:EDID HDMI VSDB supports AI:yes, dual link DVI:no
HDMI:EDID HDMI VSDB deep colour support - 48-bit:no 36-bit:yes 30-bit:yes DC_yuv444:yes
HDMI:EDID HDMI VSDB max TMDS clock 225 MHz
HDMI:EDID HDMI VSDB has no latency information
HDMI:EDID CEA extension datablock tag 0x0 is not supported
HDMI:EDID adding mandatory support for DMT (4) 640x480p @ 60Hz
HDMI:EDID adding mandatory support for CEA (3) 720x480p @ 60Hz
HDMI:EDID adding mandatory support for CEA (17) 720x576p @ 50Hz
HDMI:EDID adding mandatory support for CEA (18) 720x576p @ 50Hz
HDMI:EDID filtering formats with pixel clock unlimited MHz or h. blanking unlimited
HDMI:EDID best score mode initialised to CEA (1) 640x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 25 MHz (score 0)
HDMI:EDID best score mode is now CEA (1) 640x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 25 MHz (score 61864)
HDMI:EDID best score mode is now CEA (2) 720x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz (score 66472)
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (3) 720x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz has a score of 66472
HDMI:EDID best score mode is now CEA (4) 1280x720p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 74 MHz (score 190888)
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (4) 640x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 25 MHz has a score of 18432
HDMI:EDID best score mode is now CEA (5) 1920x1080i @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 74 MHz (score 5398248)
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (17) 720x576p @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz has a score of 66472
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (18) 720x576p @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz has a score of 66472
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (19) 1280x720p @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 74 MHz has a score of 117160
HDMI0:EDID preferred mode remained as CEA (5) 1920x1080i @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 74 MHz
HDMI:EDID has HDMI support and audio support
/opt/vc/bin/edidparser exited with code 0
```

I know that some variables in `/boot/config.txt` needs to be changed, but I got a bit confused.

I would like to know, from you guys, after you parsed the dump, if at all it is possible to run this display from pi and then what should be added in the config file.

I tried few combinations and they didn't work so I turn for help here. Please let me know what you think.

Best

Datta

Comment: Search for 'custom mode' in this info https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md I suggest trying with the Pi3 first.

Comment: Odd resolution esp as it states `HDMI:EDID found preferred CEA detail timing format: 1920x1080i @ 60 Hz (5)`

Comment: @Andyroo yes but it also says : HDMI:EDID found unknown detail timing format: 480x1920p hfp:30 hs:30 hbp:30 vfp:6 vs:6 vbp:6 pixel clock:66 MHz

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to get this partially working with an ultrawide screen (also 480x1920) so I think this may be the same one you are using.  For reference I am using a PI3B.

I put the following lines in my /boot/config.txt file:

```
hdmi_timings=480 0 30 30 30 1920 0 6 6 6 0 0 0 60 0 55296000 8
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_drive=2
display_rotate=1
hdmi_force_mode=1
```

I don't think all of this is needed, but I was trying different combinations and this is where I am at currently.

However although this does allow both console and GUi to work it still does not use all the width (height before rotation).  I have tried various options but cannot make the width any larger than about 70% of the screen width.

I note that if the power is low the warning flash is shown in the blank areas, so the screen is accessible by the pi.  Note also the screen works fully on a PC so the issue is a Pi config/limitation.

I have added forcing the framebuffer size and max and this seems to fix the full screen issue.

```
framebuffer_width=1920
framebuffer_height=480
max_framebuffer_width=1920
max_framebuffer_height=1920
```

note both width and height seem to need the max setting to 1920 so this is not a typo.

Comment: Is there a reason why you set the resolution to 480x1920 and then rotate, instead of setting it to 1920x480?

Comment: Yes the reason is that seems to be the native resolution of the screen.  Why it was designed that way I don’t know but that is how it reports itself in the edid data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Works like a charm. i just modify display_rotate to 3 (display_rotate=3).

Answer (score 2):

I have an 8.8" LCD with 480x1920 as well.  I have looked at this post as well as another one that is similar.

I have the same issue as you had with it no being full screen.  I added your buffer lines but it's still looks like this https://ibb.co/0GrkJpF

Here is my config.  The timings line is commented out as I was playing with different settings.  Were you able to figure it out?

```
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_drive=2
hdmi_cvt=480 1920 60
#hdmi_timings=480 0 30 30 30 1920 0 6 6 6 0 0 0 60 0 66000000 7
framebuffer_width=1920
framebuffer_height=480
max_framebuffer_width=1920
max_frambuffer_height=1920
display_rotate=3
```

Answer (score 0):

These setting work for me :
https://gist.github.com/innovodesign/3f5775d19cb890c0aa59fbb96757bf4b

Your problem could be a spelling mistake maybe ....

```
max_frambuffer_height=1920
```

should read

```
max_framebuffer_height=1920
```